# Dimension of an evaporator coil

Tags: refrigeration

I need to cool 3 galons of water from 77 to 32°F to form an ice bank that I will use to cool beer (it is a noble effort, you see).

I figured I need to install a cooling capacity of 0.34 kw to lower the temperature and form the ice in four hours.

I think I should use R134a as my refrigerant, and think I need a 1/2 hp compressor (0.34 kw plus 20%).

I want to use a single 42 feet,  5/16" copper pipe as my evaporator (26°F), and a similarly sized condenser (86°F) hopefully without forced air (ambiente temperature is 68°F), but are most uncertain about these calcs.

Guidance would be very much appreciated...

Comment: use finned pipes to increase the working surface.

Comment: Thanks, I will. Dimensions look about rigth?